# Best way to "stop" Aurora RDS PostqreSQL read instance during off-peak hours?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

We have an r6g.large write instance in our cluster which is perfectly enough for us during off-peak hours which is about 16 hours a day on workdays.

But during the 8 peak hours we would need a larger instance let's say an r6g.2xlarge minimum. Between the peak and off-peak hours it's not allowed to have any downtime!

Our solution would be to have the r6g.large write instance and use the r6g.2xlarge reader instance during the peak time. But in the off-peak hours the reader should stop completely.

But to our knowledge this on demand 6g.2xlarge reader instance can't be stopped this is a limitation of the stop function (right?).

So what's the best practice to do this? Delete the reader instance every day and create a new one? Is it a good way to do it? Seems a bit odd because we lose all the metrics and reports but running it 0-24 costs a lot.

(We tried serverless V2 but it's buggy and expensive, it has random spikes and doesn't scale down to 0.5-1 ACU we tried everything.)

Additional info: Our database is 700gb which may take a lot to start. Does it have any associated cost with it (like data transfer usage as Aurora is multi AZ)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it really comes down to whether peak times just stress it on the read end or if the read and write are both stressed. If you are just read stressed then I would look at creating read replicas using [RDS autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.Autoscaling). That would let you scale horizontally during peak times without having to manage turning on and off differently sized instances based on timers.

Another (admittedly more complex and likely less optimal) option is that if you know when your peak hours are (lets say 8-10pm every night), you could set up AWS event bridge to trigger your 2xlarge instance to turn on at 7:30 and back off at 10:30 to give yourself some buffer. Keep in mind this is only really an option if you have consistent peak times.

Comment: We have very consistent peak times and it's read end heavy.

Can the autoscaling read replica go down to zero? So do we need to have a reader instance all the time? Because during the off-peak the one writer instance is more than enough to have and we don't really want to pay for the extra instance.

Comment: Should be able to. You could set your minimum weight to be just the weight of the writer and it will scale all the way down to that. I think there might be an overhead cost to RDS autoscaling but it would be far less than just leaving a machine running that you aren't using (Especially an r6.2xl)

Comment: My problem with autoscaler is that sometimes I just don't want to start a new replica. During the night we have some very heavy background processes running on our database but it doesn't matter if it finishes in 1 hour or 5 hours.

That's why I'm thinking of starting a new large reader instance during the peak hours and stop it when we don't need that. Our writer instance can easily serve the load during the off-peak hours.

Comment: Ok in that case it might be worth configuring event bridge to have a lambda turn down your max capacity at night and then back up during the day. I don't believe you can put time guardrails on autoscaling directly but you can certainly use the api to just modify it

Comment: But back to my original question. Do you think creating and deleting the read replica every day is a normal solution? This is  actually what the auto scaler does too right?

Comment: yeah you are really just creating a read replica either way. just autoscaling would usually save you the overhead of configuring the jobs to do it manually.